# How to add Google Adsense to a Svelte/Sapper web app?

Tags: svelte, adsense, sapper

I am trying to get AdSense setup in my Sapper built website but I have had no success. I have added the code to the template.html file and it works, but I will like to show this on a specific page using a component.

The goal is to show the Ad in the Resource page, on the sidebar (see image). The widget above it, is a component that is loaded by the index.svelte page, so I'll like to do the same for the Ad.

[resource page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4K9v.png)

At the moment, I have the following:

- The AdSense script in the template.html  file, and then
- On the component OnMount function, I am grabbing the Adsense code from the template.html file and placing it on the component  inside a div, then removing it from the template.html file.

template.html

```
<footer>
    <!-- GoogleAdsence Script. -->
    <div id="gAdsense-code" style="display: none;">
        <script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-X0X0X0X0X0X0X" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Resource page Ad -->
        <ins class="adsbygoogle"
            style="display:block"
            data-ad-client="ca-pub-X0X0X0X0X0X0X"
            data-ad-slot="X0X0X0X0X0X0"
            data-ad-format="auto"
            data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
        <script>
            (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
        </script>   
    </div>
</footer>
```

adswidget.svelte

```
<script>

    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

onMount(() => {

        window.addEventListener( 'load', () => {
             //get ads-widget div
            let adWidget = document.getElementById('ads-widget');
            let adCode = document.getElementById('gAdsense-code');
            let adHtml = adCode.innerHTML;

            adCode.remove();
            
            //append Adsence code from the head on resources index file
            adWidget.innerHTML = adHtml;
        });
});
</script>

<div id="ads-widget"><!-- Adsence code inserted onMount --></div>
```

This will place the Adsense code in the right place, but the Ad will not display.
The error I get on the console is: "adsbygoogle.push() error: No slot size for availableWidth=0" (see image)
[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsIpy.png)

I have also referenced this [article](https://www.reddit.com/r/sveltejs/comments/iycjl9/how_to_make_adsense_works_with_sveltesapper/) w/o success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After coming across an [article](https://www.tutorialsbuddy.com/embed-google-adsense-code-in-react-component) that shows how to implement Adsense in React I was able to adapt it to work in Svelte. So, posting the answer in case it helps anyone else:

1. The loading script should be placed in the template.html file, before the closing body tag

**template.html**

```
...     
    <script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-pub-X0X0X0X0X0X0X" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

2. Place the 'adsbygoogle' code inside the component's OnMount() function. But, with a slight modification. Instead of `(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle ...)` you would do `(window.adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle ...)`
3. Also, add the `<ins>` tag inside the same component after your styles. So the file would look something like this:

**AdsWidget.svelte**

```
<script>
       onMount(() => {
      (window.adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    });
</script>

<style>
...
</style>

<div class="ads-widget-container">
  <ins class="adsbygoogle"
      style="display:block"
      data-ad-client="ca-pub-X0X0X0X0X0X0X"
      data-ad-slot="X0X0X0X0X0X0"
      data-ad-format="auto"
      data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
</div>
```

4. Of course, make sure you import the component where you need to show it.

And thats all. Hope this helps someone save some time.

Comment: Is this answer still up to date?